# parsing inline variables from string from file in php

Tags: php, string, file, parsing, variables

I'm localizing a website that I've built. I'm doing this by having a .lang file read and each line (syntax: key=string) is placed in a variable depending on the chosen language.

This array is then used to place the strings in the correct places.

The problem I'm having is that certain strings need to have hyperlinks in the middle of them for example someplace I've put my name that links to my contact page. Or a lot of the readouts of the website need to be in the strings.

To solve this I've defined a variable that holds the html + Forecaster + html,
and the localization file contains the $Forecaster variable in the string.

The problem with this as I promptly discovered is that it stubbornly refuses to parse the inline variables in the strings from the file.

Instead it prints the string and variable name as it looks in the file.

And I have yet to find a way to make it parse the variables.

For example "Heating up took $str_time" would be printed on the page exactly like that, instead of inputting the previously defined value of $str_time.

I currently use fopen() and fgets() to open and read the lines. I then explode them to separate the key and the string and then place these into the array.

Is there a way to make it parse the variables, or alternatively is there another way of reading the lines that allows for parsing the inline variables?

The code that gets the line and converts it to the array looks like this:

(It obviously loops through the lines)

```
#list($key, $string) = explode('=', $line);
$key = strtok($line, '=');
$string = strtok('=');
$local[$key] = $string;
$counter++;
echo  $local[$key] . "<br>";
```

The counter is unused and the echo is for testing.

A line from the .lang file looks like this:

```
fuel.results.heatup.timeused=Heating up took $str_time
```

I would call the array where I want the string like this:

```
$local['fuel.results.heatup.timeused']
```

As you can see I've tried both explode and strtok but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Please show your code. Do you use double quotes as string delimiter ?

Comment: Instead of “creating” variables yourself, why not just have _real_ PHP code in this file that defines variables and just include it? (Btw., instead of single variables in global scope, I’d rather go for an array that holds the translations, and not make it global, but wrap it in a function that returns it.)

Comment: If I was the only one who would be making language files I would just use php files.

But since others will be able to provide translations I'd like to keep the .lang file as simple as possible.

Comment: Of course I don't use " as a delimiter. I use the = as the delimiter to separate the key from the string.

Comment: Removing the explode stuff yelds the same result. It seems the issue is in fgets or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd write your text file in JSON format to make it easier to pull data out.

Here is a solution directly from the php manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

It is worth noting that eval() can be very dangerous used in the wrong way so make sure you're code is very secure E.g. if someone altered your txt file with real PHP code they could execute it directly on the server.

Another approach would require you to know all your variable names and could then do something like:

```
$str = 'Heating up took $str_time';
echo 'str=' . str_replace('$str_time', $str_time, $str);
```

Or do this via an array:

```
$str = 'Heating up took $str_time as well as $other_value';
$vars = Array('str_time', 'other_value');
foreach($vars as $varName) {
  $str = str_replace('$' . $varName, $$varName, $str);
}
echo 'str=' . $str;
```

Comment: Eval doesn't work. And it would be potentially unsafe since people would be able to add extra code to the lang files, but I obviously wouldn't use those. (Users can't upload files directly, they go through me).

The second solution works, but will require a bunch of extra code, but so far it's the most viable solution.

Comment: You could add all your variables to an array and loop through them to save time - see updated answer

Comment: Since I'd like to keep the definitions where they are used I will probably just write a function that substitutes the variable name in the given string with another given string. This will be simple and not require big changes to the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you not know all the variable name, you can use this example, without `eval()`. It is indicatred to avoid `eval()`.

```
$str = 'fuel.results.heatup.timeused=Heating up took $str_time';
$str_time = 'value';
if(preg_match('/\$([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $str, $v)) {
  $vname = $v[1];
  $str = str_replace('$'.$vname, $$vname, $str);
}
echo $str;      // fuel.results.heatup.timeused=Heating up took value
```

Comment: I *do* know the variable names since I define them before the place when the string is used. Language file creators are not supposed to be able to define their own variables.